# Expression for Rank 2 Tensor in Vector Notation

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, vector-analysis, tensors

How does one write the following expression

$D_{jk} (r_k \delta_{ij} - r_{i}\delta_{jk} - r_j \delta_{ik})$

in matrix notation?  Is this just

$\textbf{D} (\textbf{r} \times \textbf{I})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given expression in matrix notation should be:

$$
(\textbf{D}-\textbf{D'}- \ \text{trace}(\textbf{D}))\textbf{r}
$$

By applying the Kronecker Delta we have:
$$
D_{jk} (r_k \delta_{ij} - r_{i}\delta_{jk} - r_j \delta_{ik}) \\
=D_{jk} r_k \delta_{ij} - D_{jk}r_{i}\delta_{jk} - D_{jk}r_j \delta_{ik} \\
=D_{ik} r_k - D_{kk}r_{i} - D_{ji}r_j \\
$$

I was not able to find a cross product (Levi-Civita expression) from the given Kronecker Detla Expression.

Comment: Is r with a prime the transpose?  So it's a symmetric trace-free part of a tensor?

Comment: I did not find also the relation holds for a symmetric matrix or negative symmetric matrix.

Comment: Also, how does one write $D_{jk} r_j r_k$ as matrix notation?  This is meant to evaluate to a scalar but $\textbf{D} (\textbf{r} \textbf{r})$ is a matrix, so is it instead $\textbf{r}^T (\textbf{D} \textbf{r})$?

Comment: Following the Einstein Rule for adding common indexex, this would be a scalar (Tensor 0), and would be simply $d=D_{jk}r_jr_k=\textbf{r}^T\textbf{D}\textbf{r}$. Note also that, Tensor notation allows covariant ($r_k$) and contravariant ($r^j$ "transposed") dimensions...